# foreach construct

Tags: php

I have little confusion in `foreach` loop.

There is a `foreach` in my below code:

```
foreach ($myrows as $rows){
    $option = $rows->option_value;
    $option_value = recursive_unserialize_replace($site_url,$_POST['url_name'],$option);
    $sql.= '('."'".$rows->option_name."'".','."'".$option_value."'".','."'".$rows->autoload."'".')'.",";
}
```

Look at the line number 3. There is a comma I used to print. Now I do not want to print the comma in the last line.

Comment: so remove the comma from that code?

Comment: i think you did not get my question ? sir i want to put the comma in the every line of my output. only i dont want in the last line of my output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = array();

foreach ($myrows as $rows){
   $option = $rows->option_value;
   $option_value = recursive_unserialize_replace($site_url,$_POST['url_name'],$option);
   $array[] = '('."'".$rows->option_name."'".','."'".$option_value."'".','."'".$rows->autoload."'".')';
}

$sql = join(', ', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

After the loop, you can remove trailing commas by using the `trim()` function:

```
$sql = trim($sql, ',');
```

Comment: Is that remove the last comma only, Sorry i want only the last comma

Comment: Yes, this will trim all commas only if they are present at the beginning or at the end of the string.

Comment: It will remove any *leading* and *trailing* commas. This could be more than one, but in your case, your string starts with a bracket and ends with a bracket and a comma, so only the final comma will ever be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this at the end:

```
$sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-1);
```

This will not print the last comma.

Comment: where i have to add between the foreach loop or what ?

Comment: You need to add this after the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one more less operation and better use of memory and performance you can check also where is the pointer of foreach:

```
foreach ($myrows as $rows){
    $option = $rows->option_value;
    $option_value = recursive_unserialize_replace($site_url,$_POST['url_name'],$option);
    if ($rows === end($myrows)){
        $sql.= "('{$rows->option_name}','{$option_value}','{$rows->autoload}')";
    }else{
        $sql.= "('{$rows->option_name}','{$option_value}','{$rows->autoload}'),";
    }
}
```